# C#, NUnit: Clear way of testing that ArgumentException has correct ParamName

Tags: c#, exception, properties, nunit

To test that something throws for example an `ArgumentException` I can do this:

```
Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => dog.BarkAt(deafDog));
```

How can I check that the `ParamName` is correct in a clear way? And bonus question: Or would you perhaps perhaps recommend not testing this at all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found a pretty clear way (but please let me know if anyone have an even better one!)

```
var e = Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => dog.BarkAt(deafDog));
Assert.That(e.ParamName, Is.EqualTo("otherDog"));
```

*[Facepalm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facepalm)...*

Comment: This is my preferred approach.

Comment: Assert.IsTrue(e.ParamName=="otherDog") ? :)

Comment: @alexm: But using that would create a less obvious message when the test fails: *Expected string length 4 but was 7. Strings differ at index 0. Expected: "otherDog" But was:  "somethingElse"* vs *Expected: True But was:  False*. ;)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do more with the exception than just assert that it is thrown, then `Assert.Throws` actually returns the exception and you can do this:

```
var exception = Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => dog.BarkAt(deafDog));
// Assert something else about the exception
```

Comment: That message is just the message that will be displayed if the assertion fails?

Comment: NUnit, `Assert.Throws<T>` assertion method returns the exception.

Comment: Ah, of course you come with this while I write mine :p Will accept this then, unless someone else comes up with something even better :)

Comment: Accept your own - there's a special badge for that isn't there? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Skipping 12 years into the future -> you can now do it like this (using NUnit 3's fluent syntax):

```
TestDelegate testDelegate = () => dawg.BarkAt(xzibit);

Assert.That(testDelegate, Throws.ArgumentException.With.Property(nameof(ArgumentException.ParamName)).EqualTo("otherDawg"));
```